# Cannot access to stored images on Laravel 8 Jetstream project

Tags: php, filesystems, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

When I try to update the profile photo using jetstream laravel project functionalities, the image is stored on public/storage/profile-photos, but I cannot access it; it just does not display on the view. Also, when I submit images to the system with the following code:

```
public function registrar(array $data)
{
    //Se guarda el proyecto en la base de datos
    $producto = Producto::create($data);

    foreach ($data['imagenes'] as $imagen) {
        $ruta = $imagen->store('market/productos');

        ImagenProducto::create([
            'ruta' => $ruta,
            'producto_id' => $producto->id, 
        ]);
    }
    
    session()->flash('success', 'Producto creado satisfactoriamente.');
    return redirect()->to('/market/producto/registro');
}
```

Images are stored on /storage/app/market/productos but they're not linked with a public/storage/market/productos folder, not even executing `php artisan storage:link`.

My filesystems.php disks looks like this:

```
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

My APP_URL on .env file is `APP_URL=http://localhost`.